# Writing output XML based on adjustments to input XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm trying to refactor an existing tool to decrease memory usage. The tool processes an XML file which starts off like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="my.xsd" SchemaVersion="2.0" SoftwareVersion="2.10.6.195" ExportMode="StrongReferences" System="foo" Database="bar" Description="descriptio of bar database on foo system" Created="2021-11-10T15:14:57.8590869Z" id="9632241b-2b2b-46a4-81b0-fb9bd65c2ef5" ParentKey="a743efc8-7095-4791-b44c-da70bb01f075" ExportedObject="wibble" ExportedType="baz" Identity="bif" Persist="142 {9895150E-085D-4fcb-A16D-5EF5D2527196} 2\{a743efc8-7095-4791-b44c-da70bb01f075}\{9632241b-2b2b-46a4-81b0-fb9bd65c2ef5}*foo\bar">
  <APDatabase>
    <id>11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555</id>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Description>foo database</Description>
    <APAttCat>
      <id>22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222</id>
      <Name>just a name</Name>
    </APAttCat>
    <APElemTemp>
      <id>6012ede0-c202-4474-a13a-d9cc349c638e</id>
      <Name>name of this elem temp</Name>
      <Description>description of this elem temp</Description>
      <BaseTemplateOnly>false</BaseTemplateOnly>
      <Type>None</Type>
      <InstanceType>Elem</InstanceType>
      <AllowElemToExtend>true</AllowElemToExtend>
      <APAttTemp>
        <id>33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333</id>
        <Name>Name of this att temp</Name>
        <Description>Description of this att temp</Description>
        <Type>String</Type>
        <Value type="String"></Value>
        <AttCatRef id="44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444">!Configuration</AttCatRef>
      </APAttTemp>
    </APElemTemp>
...
```

There is a lot more in these files and they can end up being massive. The important aspect is that the first child element of each `<AP...>` XML element is an `<id>` element containing the guid for that parent element. The current program loads the whole thing into an XDocument and adds a 'delete="true"' attribute to all '<AP...>' elements where their child `<id>` element does not exist in a separate list of guids, then saves to another file.

For example, I would need to write `<APAttTemp delete="true">` if the guid for APAttTemp (33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333) is not in my separate guids list.

But loading the whole thing in chews up memory and causes issues. I want to do the same thing but without loading the entire xml into memory. Can I do this with XmlReader/XmlWriter? Is there a better way?

I am new to XML processing but so far I have got a reader and writer to open the source XML and make a duplicate of it.

As @dbc says, there is a need to look ahead at the child `<id>` element to discover whether the current element needs amending. I am thinking that maybe I can cache any `<AP...>` element and read the next `<id>` element before then writing them both to the output?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to clarify the XML you want to generate from the input XML shown?  E.g. you want to transform `<Name>` to `<Name delete="true">` because `<Name>` has no `<id>` child element, but you do not want to add it to `<ElemTemp>` because it does?  And what about `<AttCatRef id="44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444">`?  And obviously you can't delete the root element, but will it have an `<id>` child or not?

Comment: In the absence of a [mcve] my guess is that you would need to make two passes through the file, because 1) `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` are forward-only, but 2) you want to add an attribute to elements after scanning their children for an `<id>` element, which means you would need to write backwards from the current reader position.

Comment: Is the `<id>` element always the **first** child element?

Comment: Hi @dbc, yes, `<id>` is always the first element

Answer (score 0):

As you know the first element is the `id` element and all you need is to output an attribute for the parent if the value is not in a list you should be able to do that in a streaming manner, for instance using XSLT 3 with streaming (supported for the .NET framework with Saxon EE and .NET Core with SaxonCS):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="ids-to-keep" as="xs:string*" select="'11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555', '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222', '6012ede0-c202-4474-a13a-d9cc349c638e'"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'AP')]/id">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'AP')]/id/text()">
    <xsl:if test="not(. = $ids-to-keep)">
      <xsl:attribute name="delete">yes</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <id>{.}</id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" streamable="yes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It might also be possible combining XmlReader and XmlWriter to copy everyting through but write out that attribute if an id is encounter that is not on the list of ids.